# Restore items accidentally overwritten by importing a Package

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

**Problem:**

I imported a small package of about 15 items from one of our DBs to another one and somehow in the process the children of one of the items got overwritten by this operation. 
I may have incorrectly selected "overwrite" instead of "merge" but I'm not sure about that.

The worst thing is, I also published to the web DB after import, so the items are not in the web DB either.

**Things I checked:**

- Checked the Recycle Bin, not there
- Also checked the Archive, not there either
- Even wrote a piece of code to find the items by ID in the DB, FAILED

**My question:**

Are the items overwritten by Launch Wizard gone forever? Or there could still be a trace of them remaining in the DB?

Comment: As far as I know, its gone forever. I've always taken backups of DB before installing new packages. It's one of the unfortunate design principal of sitecore. Hope they give us an option to rollback in future.

Comment: Thank you @xoail . There is a backup available, but it's huge and also needs asking the IT department to restore it somewhere else. Just wanted to know if some simpler approach can be used

Comment: Unfortunately the easiest option is to restore the DB backup and then change a connection string to point to that instance (even if that is from your local machine) and then create a package of the items you want. You can then install that package back to the required instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "rollback or uninstall a package" feature out of the box in Sitecore. [This](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/916660) seems to be the only available info regarding the matter.

I've heard of [some](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/PackageHistory.aspx) shared source modules which could be useful, but never tried them personally.

I think, your best choice is to restore items from a database backup or revert content, if you have a serialized copy on the file system.

Comment: Thank you, I went straight for the DB backup option. But wanted to make sure if there is a way, for future incidents ;)